# How can changing the order of integration be used to solve the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos{(\alpha x)}-\cos{(\beta x)}}{x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, change-of-variable

I am attempting to solve the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos{(\alpha x)}-\cos{(\beta x)}}{x}\,dx$$ I know that the correct answer is $\ln{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}$ and that the integrand can be rewritten as $$\int_\alpha^\beta \sin{(xy)}\,dy$$ to form the double integral $$\int_0^\infty \int_\alpha^\beta \sin{(xy)}\,dy\,dx$$ Now if we were integrating over a finite rectangular region, I would feel comfortable using Fubini's theorem to swap the order of integration. Is there a way to switch the order of integration for a double integral of this form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

Comment: You could replace $\infty$ by a large real number $N$ and then let $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppose $ \alpha, \beta>0 $. Compute: $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (\alpha x)-\cos (\beta x)}{x}dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966023/suppose-alpha-beta0-compute-int-0-infty-frac-cos-alpha-x)