# how to evaluate this double integral by change the order?

Tags: calculus

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx$
I represented the integrand by an integral of $\sin(xy)$ to get an double integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{b}^{a} \sin(xy)dydx$
Then I want to change the order of this double integral, but I how can I solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(xy)dx$ first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppose $ \alpha, \beta>0 $. Compute: $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (\alpha x)-\cos (\beta x)}{x}dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966023/suppose-alpha-beta0-compute-int-0-infty-frac-cos-alpha-x)

Answer (score 0):

Your last integral does not exist, so you cannot use this method. For solving it, have a look at
[Proof of Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem)